# Creating A Custom Excel Report

Tags: sahi

I should be able to customize excel script reports here:
C:\Users\ [user] \sahi_pro\config\reports\excel\script_report

As explained here: http://sahipro.com/docs/faq/how-to-customize-html-reports.html

When I make changes, they don't apply.

1. Edit the script_report XSLT Stylesheet
2. Run a script
3. Go to logs
4. Click on the script that's ran. Should see the script report.
5. Click on the excel icon on the top right.

This should produce the customized excel report.

I tested to see if the html reports could be edited and I can custom html reports anyway I want using this method.

Comment: so.. what is the problem?

Comment: Making changes to that file does not change the reports.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the XSLT Stylesheets seem to be working for the html reports, not excel sheets. To write custom excel reports, I am using the "Sahi Pro - File Manipulation APIs" in my scripts.

http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/file-apis.html#_writeCSVFile